# NotifyIconWpf ShowCustomBalloon change default position

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the code from this CodeProject article: [WPF NotifyIcon](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon?msg=5449071#xx5449071xx)

The custom balloon is shown at the right bottom of the screen by default but I need help changing the code to have it position the balloon at the bottom, left.

Comment: What is `NotifyIconWpf`?

Comment: see the project here  : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon?msg=5449071#xx5449071xx

Comment: The position is not under your control.  Windows displays the balloon and it ensures that the balloon stem overlaps the icon inside the tray.  Right-bottom is where almost any Windows user has it, albeit that they can move it by relocating the taskbar.  It isn't actually a balloon anymore either, a toast on Win10.  So your balloon works just like any other balloon displayed by any program.  So by and large, if you need it on the left then you are just using the wrong feature.

Answer (score 1):

Change the x,y computed by `TrayInfo.GetTrayLocation()` in `TrayInfo.cs` to use the opposite side of `rcWorkArea` than it currently does.

Note that Windows lets you position the taskbar on any edge of the screen so the logic in `GetTrayLocation` checks that in `info.Edge`.  So, the `Left/Right/Top/Bottom` of `rcWorkArea` used will need to be opposite from how it's currently coded depending upon which edge of the screen has the taskbar.